# Open ng-zorro-antd popover at current mouse position

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I'm using the [ng-zorro popover](https://ng.ant.design/components/popover/en) in an Angular 10 app.

When I click on the page, I'd like an instance of the popover to be shown at the current location of the mouse.

Any suggestions on how can this be quickly implemented? The code samples only seem to show how to display a popover when you click an existing element - button, link etc.

Comment: Were you able to find your solution for this?

Comment: Found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been implemented for the dropdown component already! So you could use the dropdown component instead or try swapping the template in the example to use the tooltip component.

Look at the “context menu” demo here: https://ng.ant.design/components/dropdown/en#components-dropdown-demo-context-menu

It leverages the “(contextMenu)” property to trigger the appearance of a context menu within the defined div.

Hope this helps!